# How to Have better on-screen Gesture-control in CM13 of many phones?

Tags: cyanogenmod, gestures

There is currently drawing circle (camera) and drawing V (flashlight). However, I would like to have other shortcuts such as drawing up-arrow. 
I have noticed that the first two gestures are specific to Oneplus phones. 
I have not managed to get them for Samsung phones. 
So it would be great to find some software which gives you sufficient gesture-control in all phones.

Phone: Oneplus 2, Samsung Galaxy S4, ...
OS: Cyanogenmod 13

Comment: IMO, the question would become more clear if you replace *gesture* with *off-screen gesture*, since there are already multiple apps that can help with on-screen gestures.

Comment: @Firelord I changed it to on-screen gesture-control, because I think touching is about it.

Comment: Have you tried https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodmooddroid.gesturecontroldemo?

Comment: @firelord Tested now but it just loops trying to get root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported by default at the moment. Waiting for better sensors in the devices.